# View Tiff files from a folder one by one using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working on project where I have TIFF files in a folder and I want to view those in browser one by one using First, Next, previous, last buttons on the screen. Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this?

I am able to view single file using iTextSharp, but how to proceed for above? Please help.

Comment: hello sushil, welcome to stackoverflow. please read the article [ask]. what have you tried?

Comment: what kind of application do you plan?

Comment: it is web based application where i have to show tiff files using above buttons.

Comment: there are tons of technologies that are web based... what do you use? asp.net mvc, webforms, wcf service?

Comment: we cannot help you unless you are more specific... a code snippet of where you are stuck ... the information of the project type etc...

Comment: put yourself in the role of the reader of the question and ask yourself ... do i have enough information to answer the question... if that's the case you are golden and will get precise answers